# About definition: For any subspaces V and W, let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear: $N(T)$={$ x \in V | T(x)= 0_W$}

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> For any subspaces V and W, let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear:
>    $N(T)$={$ x \in V | T(x)= 0_W$}
>
> R(T)={$T(x) | x \in V$}={$y \in W\mid\;\exists x \in V$ with $y=T(x)$}

Based on the definition, can I claim that $N(T) \in R(T)$?

Comment: No. $N$ is a subspace of $V$ and $R$ is a subspace of $W$.

Comment: You're essentially asking whether the kernel of $T$ is equal to the image of $T$, which even if $V=W$ would not be necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(T)$, a.k.a. the kernel of $T$, commonly denoted by $\ker(T)$, is a subspace of $V$.

$R(T)$, a.k.a. the image of $T$, commonly denoted by $\text{im}(T)$, is a subspace of $W$.

So "$N(T)\in R(T)$" doesn't make much sense. Even if you replace "$\in$" with "$\subseteq$" this still won't happen most of the time, even when $V=W$.

For example consider

$$T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$T(x)=0$$

and note that $N(T)=\mathbb{R}$ while $R(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: I am a little confused, isn't 0 is a real number?

Comment: @xyz12354 I've actually meant the example to be the constant 0 map.